# Tennis rules question regarding serving out of sequence rule

Tags: rules, tennis, serve

In the UK, the LTA, basically the UK tennis governing body has a rule:

If a player serves out of turn during a standard game, the player who was originally due to serve will serve as soon as the error is discovered. However, if a game is completed before the error is discovered the order of service will remain as altered.

I am trying to understand how this would work in the case that the error is discovered after an out of sequence serve.

Scenario is we have player A and player B, A wins toss and decides to serve first. What happens if A serves for game 1 and A serves for game 2, then at the end of game 2 they realise that A should not have served game 2.  Does A go onto serve game 3 and they then carry on as normal, or does B serve game 3 and they then carry on alternating.

Comment: That's exactly what the sentence "if a game is completed before the error is discovered the order of service will remain as altered." covers. Game 2 is completed, the altered order that A serves even and B serves odd games will remain, so B will serve game 3.